# How to build Mojarra from source

Tags: java, maven, build, jar, mojarra

I downloaded the Mojarra source code from [here](https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/org/glassfish/javax.faces/2.1.9/). I also downloaded the pom file to build the source code files. It turns out that the code structure is different from the original and I need to create directories and but the files there.

I created this directory structure:

```
laptop@Laptop javax.faces-2.1.9-sources]$ tree

.
|-- pom.xml
`-- src
    `-- main
        |-- java
        |   |-- com
        |   |   `-- sun
        |   |       `-- faces ....(other sub directories)
        |   `-- javax
        |       `-- faces ....(other sub directories)
        `-- resources
            `-- META-INF
                `-- MANIFEST.MF
```

I created the directories `src`, `main`, `java` and `resources` and I placed the source code directories in those directories but it's not working. What is the proper way to place the source code files into the the package?

Best wishes

Answer (score 4):

As of **Jan 16, 2017**, you can build Mojarra using the following steps:

**Note:** building Mojarra requires that `ant` and `maven` be installed on your system. It also requires that you are using the correct JDK version:

- For Mojarra `2.3.x` use JDK `8` (or `1.8`).
- For Mojarra `2.2.x` use JDK `7` (or `1.7`).
- For Mojarra `2.1.x` use JDK `6` (or `1.6`) (I haven't actually tested this).

---

1. Download the source from `git://java.net/mojarra~git`:

   ```
   git clone git://java.net/mojarra~git
   ```
2. Navigate to your new **`mojarra~git`** directory:

   ```
   cd mojarra~git/
   ```
3. Copy **`build.properties.glassfish`** to **`build.properties`**:

   ```
   cp build.properties.glassfish build.properties
   ```
4. Set the `jsf.build.home` property in your **`build.properties`** file:

   ```
   jsf.build.home=/path/to/mojarra
   ```

   Here's a (GNU) `sed` command to do this:

   ```
   sed -i "s|jsf[.]build[.]home=.*|jsf.build.home=$PWD|" build.properties
   ```
5. **Mojarra `2.3.x` Note:** *skip this step.*

   Run `ant` to build the Mojarra build tools:

   ```
   ant main clean main
   ```
6. Run one of the following `ant` commands to build Mojarra:

   1. Run the following command if you want to build Mojarra as a single **`javax.faces.jar`**:

      ```
      ant clean main mvn.deploy.snapshot.local
      ```

      The newly built Mojarra jar will be located in **`jsf-ri/build/mvn/target`** as **`javax.faces-${mojarra.version}.jar`**.

      **Mojarra `2.3.x` Note:** *the newly built JSF/Mojarra API jar will be located in* **`jsf-api/build/mvn/target`** *as* **`javax.faces-api-${mojarra.version}.jar`**.
   2. **Mojarra `2.3.x` Note:** *this command may not work for Mojarra `2.3.x`.*

      Run the following command if you want to build Mojarra as a two jars,  **`jsf-api.jar`** and **`jsf-impl.jar`**:

      ```
      ant clean main mvn.pre-maven-rename.deploy.snapshot.local
      ```

      The newly built Mojarra API jar will be located in **`jsf-api/build.pre-maven-rename/mvn-pre-maven-rename/target`** as **`jsf-api-${mojarra.version}.jar`**. The newly built Mojarra jar will be located in **`jsf-ri/build.pre-maven-rename/mvn-pre-maven-rename/target`** as **`jsf-impl-${mojarra.version}.jar`**.

The Mojarra snapshot jar(s) will also be installed in your local **`~/.m2/`** repository for maven purposes.

Comment: When building `MOJARRA_2_2X_ROLLING` you may run into an SSL exception or handshake error when downloading dependencies from sourceforge. You can fix this by updating your JRE's certificates. I found that the easiest way to update was to copy the **`cacerts`** file from a newer JDK: `cp $JDK_8_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts $JDK_7_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts`.